# How to display the result of 2 variables laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display the results of 2 functions from the controller on the home page.
I want to count from the computers table how many DELLs there are and how many IBMs.

```
public function ibm()
    {
        $ibm= DB::table('computers')
            ->where( 'name', 'IBM')->count();
 
        return view('welcome', ['ibm'=>$ibm]);
 
    }
 
 
    public function dell()
    {
        $dell= DB::table('computers')
            ->where( 'name', 'DELL')->count();
 
        return view('welcome', ['dell'=>$dell]);

 }
```

Route web.php:

```
Route::get('welcome','ComputerController@ibm');
Route::get('welcome','ComputerController@dell');
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<php>

   DELL<p>{{  $dell ?? '' }}</p>

    IBM<p>{{  $ibm ?? '' }}</p>
</php>
```

Unfortunately, I only get the result of one of the variables. The other does not display the result

Comment: If you need them on the same page, make it a single action that fetches data for both. You can't define multiple routes with the same path and method.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define same URI with same method route at a time, so delete one :

```
Route::get('welcome','ComputerController@ibm');
```

And your controller will be :

```
public function ibm()
{
    $ibm= DB::table('computers')
        ->where('name', 'IBM')->get()->count();
    $dell= DB::table('computers')
        ->where('name', 'DELL')->get()->count();
 
    return view('welcome', ['ibm' => $ibm, 'dell' => $dell]);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have empty results. Both variables.

Comment: hmm... No changes

Comment: Do you have data with name `IBM` on the `name` field?

Comment: Try running 
```dd($ibm) ``` before returning the view then share the outcome!

Comment: Now I only have the result of the first variable. The second is empty.

Comment: dd($ibm) I got the result - 14, dd($dell) I got the result - 10

Comment: The function works, but only in a newly created clear view, e.g. report.blade.php. If I want to display it in welcome.blade.php view I have empty results. I do not know why...

Comment: @mike both function `public function ibm()` and `public function dell()` both are different function, and they can't share variable between them, so you need to pass variable variable manually

Comment: Interestingly, the newly created clear view works as it should. I need to count from one table the number of computers e.g. DELL or IBM. Maybe the problem is in Route.